# iOS Enterprise distribution won't install

Tags: ios

I get the following error when I try to install my app, which is distributed via Enterprise Distribution:

```
Couldn't read PKZip Signature

 Unable to extract archive. Please make sure /var/....path to .pkg is a valid zip or ipa archive.
```

I have a valid account, valid certificates, valid everything. And the funny thing is that it worked before new year, before the newest update to Xcode. After the update, everything went to hell.

And yes, LSRequiresIPhoneOS is set to YES (has always been).

No information on the internet has helped me solve this, and it is critical. My client is literally screaming at me, and I scream at Apple, and there is no solution in sight, and I am starting to give up...

Comment: In keychain access application are any of the certs in there messed up? I recently had an issue installing apps on developer devices and I had to update some Apple Worldwide Developer Relations certificate or something and everything started working again. Looks like February 14, 2016 if you didn't update it things may stop working and it includes enterprise apps. https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Comment: It sounds like maybe the .ipa got corrupted.  If you download the file on your Mac, can you change the extension to.zip and extract it?

Comment: The IPA can be renamed to ZIP and extracted without problems. I Went through the steps mentioned in the link above about the AWDR cert expiring (it had expired). But nothing has changed. I still get and error saying that the PKZIP signature can't be read.